# Why date.gettime() always returns Previous Date, not today's date in java?

Tags: java

I have following code, running on Unix server (WAS 5.1), it's a test environment in our company. When I try to execute the below code, I always get yesterday's date (i.e if I execute today 9/27/2012 it returns date as 9/26/2012)

```
long userSelectedTimeLong = date.getTime()
```

Comment: `System.out.println(new Date(new Date().getTime()));` prints the today's date by me...

Comment: When I tried that code, it gave me milliseconds as "1348717971579" and when I converted that to actual date, I am getting date as "Wednesday, September 26, 2012 11:52:51 PM EDT"

Comment: You difference of 9 hours. Which means you are passing wrong time zone value while converting date to EDT. EDT == GMT-4 hours

Comment: @AmitD.. can I give timezone while creating date only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date returns time based on `TimeZone` of the machine. It is possible that your sever might be hosted some where else and TimeZone value is different.
You need to compare value of date by having same TimeZone.

Once you do that next task is is `date` variable really contains current date. You can print a simple log using `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: and if you are working with timezone info also, use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem once ;-)
Check wether the local date variable is instantiated when the application launches and perhabs not being refreshed while the application runs.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good use
`long userSelectedTimeLong = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility : does the server sync with some kind of time service ? (ntp, ...)
Maybe it 's just the system date on the Unix machine that has been set wrong.